# An dropdown autocomplete reactive input box in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, search, html, inputbox

I want to create a reactive input box exactly like the one that can be seen on [Zomato.com](https://www.zomato.com/). I was wondering hwo i could do it with a good looking template. Please help !

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Comment: Now how can I add CSS to this to make it look just as good as the example in the website ?

Comment: Now how do add CSS to this to make look just as good as the example. Also you notice that the website doesn't have a basic datalist and is reactive to when the user drops down the list or clicks the textbox to make an input. I was wondering how that can be achieved

Comment: try somthing make a working fiddle, and we will help you, or hire some freeelancer